# Android App - File access fails on ChromeOS

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

My Android file browser fails to run on ChromeOS so I made a small test application to access files on my Chromebook. This fails, too:

The program checks the start location exists (in this case "/"):

```
File currentFolder;
String pathname = "/";
currentFolder = new File(pathname);
if(currentFolder.exists()) {
```

And then goes on to find out what is in there:

```
        // continues
        File[] directories = currentFolder.listFiles();
        int size = directories.length;
        // display code etc.
}
```

Problem: currentFolder.listFiles() closes the program on ChromeOS (see edit below - the array is empty).

Unfortunately, I cannot get debug logging on my Chrome tablet via USB or Wireless [by following the instructions](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/development-environment#debug_with_adb) (my Asus tablet [does not seem capable](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-adb-debugging-over-usb)) and the Android Studio emulator fails to run on my machine:

```
Emulator: virto-goldfish-pipe fatal error: init:475: Could not get virtio gpu ops!
Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

So I can't even debug things to find out what is going wrong. The application just vanishes with no information. I'd love to have a proper debugger running...

I'm using Android permissions in my Manifest (that work fine on my Android device):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Are there any other permissions I need to request from ChromeOS? My browser needs to access the MicroSD on Chromebooks where I have files stored in a fixed location. Is there something different I need to do to access the storage directly? I'm worried it might be protected from Android apps...

Comment: I did a little more on this and caught the exception being thrown - a null pointer exception (Attempt to get length of a null array).

Comment: `currentFolder.listFiles() closes the program on ChromeOS` No. But it returns `null` hence the following statement: `int size = directories.length;` will cause a NullPointerException as you have seen.

Comment: So check for null before use and dont continue if null.

Comment: "/" has not much to do with the path to a removable micro sd card. "/" Is not listable since Android N already.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for the feedback. Do you know what folder should I look at for MicroSD on ChromeOS?

Comment: I think you will get that folder in the same way as usual in Android. I have no Chrome laptop and cannot check but why should it be different? Did you try in the normal way?

Comment: I have no idea how to find that without being able to browse the directory structure from the root. Do you know another way?

Comment: As said your way is not possible already since Android N. Have a look at the second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: Thank you, black. I will look at this tomorrow. It's been a few years since I've touched Android and I just need to update my app to have it working on ChromeOS (not for public release).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219529/discussion-between-david-and-blackapps).